# How to remove background color of active button in @react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs` and I would like to remove background color of active button. Which props should I use? I tried almost everything from documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding theme to your app.

First install : npm i react-native-paper

Use it like this :
import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper';

Then create theme :

const theme = {
colors: {
primary: '#3498db',
accent: '#f1c40f',
},
};

Then wrap your app with PaperProvider:

```
import React from 'react'; import Navigation from './src/navigation'; import { Provider as PaperProvider } from 'react-native-paper'; const theme = { colors: {  primary: '#3498db',accent: '#f1c40f',},}; const App =() => { return ( <>
<PaperProvider theme={theme}>
<Navigation />
</PaperProvider> </> );}; export default App;
```